# Best way to call an external js file from the HTML page (as of July 2017)

Tags: javascript, html, external

As of July 2017, what is the best practice for calling an external Javascript file from an HTML page?

1) In the HEAD with a DEFER attribute:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

2) In the HEAD without a DEFER attribute and placing all the js code in a function which fires after the DOM is loaded.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

script.js file:

```
function init() {
    // all JS code in here
}
window.onload = init;
```

3) Immediately BEFORE the closing BODY tag:

```
...
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

4) Immediately AFTER the closing BODY tag:

```
...
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

5) Some other way?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to call an external javascript is 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" async></script>` before the closing tag for for body (`</body>`).

`async` allows the DOM to not stop its process when it finds a `<script>` tag.

For more information, refer to this post https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS

Comment: Do you have a source or documentation that can support this?

Comment: @hwdbc Yes, I do have a documentation. I passed the Google Mobile Sites Certification a couple of days ago. It was part of the exam. https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS

Comment: Thanks for delivering on that. I asked because it would be helpful for OP to have access to good documentation.

Comment: @hwdbc It makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would you still recommend this approach if you had a significant portion of users who were on "older" versions of Internet Explorer? My very large user base switched to IE11 (from IE8) about a year and a half ago. I'm guessing there are many users that have not upgraded to IE11.

Comment: Yes, it will work for users who are still using older versions of Internet Explorer.